# ECONNRESET on POST request from Postman to localhost while Get request is ok

Tags: post, postman, econnreset

I am having same error on Node Express server accessing ElephantSQL postgre via pgAdmin 4. Testing api's from Postman. Get request returns ok while post request results in ECONNRESET error. I checked suggestions above, url, ssl off, etc

```
GET http://localhost:5000/manufacturers
200
272 ms
POST http://localhost:5000/manufacturers
Error: read ECONNRESET
Request Headers
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.31.3
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: be861185-51ed-421c-8939-7a059592c367
Host: localhost:5000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Request Body
```

Comment: In your log, it's GET, not POST. `GET http://localhost:5000/manufacturers`